# Angular Material Table Got collapsed while Rendering more than 20 Columns

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, material-ui

I am working in Angular Version 5. In Angular Material Table Got collapsed while Rendering more than 20 Columns.
This how my Table Look Like. 
Please help me resolve this issue.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because Angular material table is behaves like this. Try to make it responsive with horizontal scrollbar.
Refer this example : 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mdxik6?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html

Comment: 0


I have implemented responsiveness in my table. But my Border bottom is incompleted please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: add this in your css:

.mat-header-row, .mat-row {
    display: inline-flex;
}